# Android app continues to run in external browser after redirect

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, url-scheme

As outlined in the title, when one of my app's activities are called with a custom scheme from an external browser (tested with Firefox), it correctly returns to the activity and proceeds like normal. However, the issue is that if I were to open up Task View, I would see that the activity was continuing within the browser task, and my app's task is left at a previous activity.

I start the browser with:

```
val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
i.data = Uri.parse(authUrl)
startActivity(i)
```

which, eventually, leads to a redirect to my app with a custom scheme:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<data android:host="callback"
      android:scheme="d2app"
      android:pathPattern=".*"/>
```

But as you could see [here](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/295883437938573313/632207667099598848/Screenshot_20191012-002715.jpg)
the browser remains the active task and the app proceeds within it.

Is there a certain flag/set of flags I should be adding to the browser intent? Am I missing something important with the intent filters for the activity? Thanks for any help/pointers you can give.

I apologise if I'm mixing up basic terminology here, I'm very new to app development as a whole.

Comment: have you tried adding the taskaffinity to the intent. just add -->
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

Comment: @vikaskumar I have but, unfortunately, it doesn't fix the issue. I've tried setting the flags both before and after starting the browser activity, but still nothing. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

I appear to have fixed my problem by adding `android:launchMode="singleTask"` to the activity declaration in the manifest, to force it to swap back to the original instance of the activity.